# Slim 3 blackholing errors

Tags: slim

I have a small slim 3 app, and when I throw an exception slim simply shows the generic error message:

> ## Slim Application Error
>
> A website error has occurred. Sorry for the temporary inconvenience.

In slim 2 you can do something like this to turn on debug mode giving you backtraces etc:

```
$app->config('debug', true);
```

In slim 3 there doesn't seem to be one. Additionally, it seems to be overriding my exception and error handlers.

How can I get slim to spit out errors, or at least to call my error handlers (Which pipe the output to kint for debug information)

Comment: Which version of Slim 3 are you using?

Comment: `3.0.0-RC3` - but it was doing this with RC2 as well

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looking through the source, it's possible to initialize slim 3 with error display like so:

```
$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => ['displayErrorDetails' => true]]);
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to change this setting after the fact without replacing the `errorHandler` altogether.

Answer (score 2):

To show full stack trace on default exception handler use what j-v said.

If you want to handle exceptions in Slim yourself then you need to override Slim's default exception handler as it will be used before your "not in Slim" error handler:

```
$app = new \Slim\App();

$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['errorHandler'] = function(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, Exception $exception) {
    //Handle exception here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Error handling is rather well documented: [Official Docs](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/handlers/error.html)

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$c = $app->getContainer();
$c['errorHandler'] = function ($c) {
    return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($c) {
         return $c['response']->withStatus(500)
                              ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
                              ->write('Something went wrong!');
         };
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

Error handling is best solution to this. You can do something like to see **Error Trace**

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['phpErrorHandler'] = $container['errorHandler'] = function ($c) {
    return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($c) {
         return $c['response']->withStatus(500)
                              ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
                              ->write('Something went wrong!<br><br>' . 
                                      nl2br($error->getTraceAsString()));
         };
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Make displayErrorDetails->true.
You will find cause of error.

```
 $config = ['settings' => [
        'addContentLengthHeader' => true,
        'displayErrorDetails' => true
    ]];
    $app = new \Slim\App($config)
```